# Unit testing the obvious

Tags: unit-testing, jakarta-ee, junit, dependency-injection, tdd

While trying to write test cases for a class whose functionality deals more with boiler plate code than business logic. I started wondering if unit testing is really worth for this class. But then again, when using TDD, we are advised to write test for any piece of logic we add.

As an example the below class, just uses DI to inject dependencies and get config parameters to set up the running of the application. Other than unit testing if dependencies are correctly injected, or if destroy is called when running finishes(which would be unit testing the java CDI framework than my own code), what else I can unit test?

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttribute;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttributeType;
import javax.inject.Inject;

@Singleton
@Startup
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
public class PipsAlprConnectionRunner {
    @Inject
    private PipsAlprConfiguration config;

    @Inject
    private PipsAlprConnector connector;

    @Inject
    private Scheduler scheduler;

    @Inject
    @PipsAlprAdapterService
    private ServiceStatus status;

    private Timer connectorTimer = null;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialized() {
        status.started();
        connectorTimer = scheduler.schedule(connector, 0,
                1000 * config.getPollPeriodSeconds());
        status.operational();
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy() {
        connectorTimer.cancel();
        connector.shutdown();
        status.stopped();
    }
}
```

I was unable to think of any testing scenarios to utilize TDD, on the above class, so just came up with the code, and now i am wondering what exactly can i unit test here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a case can be made that the class does something. It changes a status, it starts a timer. You can inject mocks of these objects into the class via Mockito and then make sure, that `initialized()` and `destroy()` both do what you expect them to do to these mocks.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class PipsAlprConnectionRunner {

    @Mock
    private PipsAlprConfiguration config;

    @Mock
    private PipsAlprConnector connector;

    @Mock
    private Scheduler scheduler;

    @Mock
    private ServiceStatus status;     

    @InjectMocks
    private PipsAlprConnectionRunner pipsAlprConnectionRunner ;

    @Test
    public void initialized_should_set_status_started() {
         pipsAlprConnectionRunner.initialized();
         Mockito.verify(status).started();
    }

    // etc.
}
```

It's pretty much a question of personal taste if you want to create one method per "point of failure" or one method per method/test.

Personally, I would say that the goal is 100% coverage, so even pretty simple classes that mainly delegate should be covered. What happens if someone changes anything? The test ensures that such changes will not break existing functionality.

Comment: So i believe the PipsAlprConnectionRunner class you defined is actually a test class different from the actual PipsAlprConnectionRunner ? And all the objects will be inserted with mock implementation through DI? How about the unit test where you check if the dependency is actually injected?  But i believe such a test is useless since CDI injection wont happen during a unit test run

Comment: No, the `PipsAlprConnectionRunner` is actually your `PipsAlprConnectionRunner`. Mockito will create one and inject the mocked depedencies into it, that's the magic of `@InjectMocks` Personally, I wouldn't test the DI for itself, since that would effectively test the framework (ok, we could make an argument for the idea that we are testing that the correct annotations are there). I would simply make some integration tests at a later stage that will depend on DI anyway and thus test that automatically.

Comment: I see Thanks! Also since the started() and destroy() method change the internal state of PipsAlprConnectionRunner the only way to test it is through behavior verification then state verification? But that can only be done through mock objects, what if we werent using a mocking framework? Or how would people do unit testing on objects whose state was hard to verify before the advent of mock objects?

Comment: Fake objects. You can simply extend your class to one without behavior that lets you ask it "was this method called"? Of course, you have to write one for each class, etc. thus making it quite a hassle. But fortunately, we now have mocks and don't have to worry ;-)

Comment: A pattern i see a lot is using strategy pattern to subclass an interface for a fake object with dummy values and inject that into a class needed for unit testing but not already implemented. I believe this is what you meant? Usually i have seen this pattern for returning fixed values to be used for testing. But we can also utilize this pattern for testing behavior verification?

Comment: Because i believe mocking framework offer way to make a mock object return values we desire on method calls such as         when(test.getUniqueId()).thenReturn(43);
This i believe was the mock replacement for the strategy pattern testing i described above. But mock also provides behavior verification, which i always wondered how was done before mocking framework existed.

Comment: I don't quite understand why you think it would be hard to simply add a, let's say, Map<String, Object[]> to your fake object, override each method to store the name and parameters of the method in the map and then offer that map to the outside, so you can check if the method was called with the given parameters...

Comment: Interesting! One last question before i stop bothering you. In the above class all the dependencies being injected are private to the class. Usually the reason to unit test is to verify how the object interacts and behave with  through its API. If we get hung up on all those private fields, and how exactly initialze() or destroy() produces the desire result by testing if it called started(), then it set the connection timer and then called operational(), wouldnt we be breaking the code even on a slight refactor, even though if the desired overall effect is same?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122327/discussion-between-florian-schaetz-and-saad).